# How to change woo-commerce product category url?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have set up WordPress WooCommerce website. Default product category URL is like
http://localhost/woocommerce/product-category/test/.

But I want to change this URL like http://localhost/woocommerce/test/product-category.

Is it possible to change the category URL format into which I want?

Comment: Check under settings as in the screenshot below

Answer (score 11):

Under WordPress Settings->Permalinks
https://example.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in Settings > Permalinks.

If you only need to customize category archives URL, the right parameter to change is **Product Category Base**

[image]

If you want to customize final product URL you can change parameter in **Custom Base** and insert your own slug, or slug + product_cat placeholder link in this example : /test/%product_cat%/

[image]

Thank save the changes of course.

Cheers,
Francesco

Comment: Worked perfectly. THanks

Comment: it's not working for subcategory permalink